# Problem with High Order Component using typescript with FlatList

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-native-flatlist, high-order-component

**question:**

I need to use an High Order Component that can infer type for `FlatList` with `typescript`.

```
<CustomFlatList<MyObject> 
// props
/>
```

How can I do without errors?

**explanations:**

I decided to create a component with custom injected `Props` into any `FlatList`s of my app.

I thought an High Order Component was best suited to the situation.

```
// my code so far

interface InjectedProps {
  customProps: any;
}

export const withCustomProps = <T extends object>(Component: React.ComponentType<T>): React.FC<T & InjectedProps> => ({
   customProps,
   ...props
 }: InjectedProps) => {
   // a bit of more logic
   return <Component {...(props as T)} />;
 };

export const CustomFlatList = withCustomProps(FlatList);
```

**But**, not really: everything works fine, **excepted** with `typescript`. When I try to strongly type my `FlatList` in order to infer the other props methods (such as `renderItem`) I`ve got an error:

```
<CustomFlatList // works
// props
/>



<CustomFlatList<MyObject> // Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1
// props
/>
```

For now, I have no choice but to use `any` for the rendering method definition.

```
renderItem={ ({ item }: { item: any }) => {//whatever} }
```

I also tried to mimic the syntax of `FlatList` -- using two nested generic types (`T` and `ItemT`)

```
// React definition of FlatList
export class FlatList<ItemT = any> extends React.Component<FlatListProps<ItemT>>
```

```
// My buggy code
export const withCustomProps = <T extends object, ItemT>(Component: React.ComponentType<T<ItemT>>): React.FC<T & InjectedProps> => ({
  customProps,
  ...props
}: InjectedProps) => {
  return <Component {...(props as T)} />;
};

export const CustomFlatList = withCustomProps(FlatList);
```

But I've got yet another `typescript` error:

```
Type 'T' is not generic.
```

Comment: try `export const withCustomProps = <T extends object>(Component: ComponentType<T>): FC<T & InjectedProps> => <T extends object>({customProps, ...props}: InjectedProps) => {
        // a bit of more logic
        return <Component {...(props as T)} />;
    }
`

Comment: @arslan2012 thanks! but this doesnt seems to work. Could you provide a full working example?

Comment: what seems to be the problem, i tested it and it's working

Comment: The second `<T extends object>`  is not used, the code work but I cannot use `<CustomFlatList<MyObject> ...
/>` without typescript error Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1.ts
. by the way I use ESlint.

Comment: `export const CustomFlatList = withCustomProps<MyObject>(FlatList);`

Comment: What's the purpose of doing this? What do you want to achieve by wrapping a component in another component?

Comment: @Aron good question: I automatically enable or disable the scoll depending of the size of the screen (with `useDimensions()`)

Comment: Are you doing that in the HOC? Or outside of it and passing the dimensions in as `customProps`?

Comment: @Aron inside the HOC yes, the `customProps` are used to handle the extra height if the `FlatList` doesn't take all the screen.

Comment: I could copy/paste the entire component so you can have a better understanding. But  I'm not sure it's relevant to the original question.